# Programatically turn off backspace mass delete feature of iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to disable the iOS keyboard's feature where when you hold backspace down for long enough it starts to delete many characters at a time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UITextViewDelegate (or UITextFieldDelegate method) shouldChangeTextInRange stop the user from deleting words at a time.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
        if (text.length == 0) {
            //Backspace
            return range.length == 1;
        }
        return YES;
}
```